# Mention that the commented user is online when asked to move discussion to chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

I have a suggestion

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to
>   automatically move this discussion to chat?

In this part why can't we mention that the commented user is online or not?

**Reasons for this feature:**

Without knowing whether the commented user is online entering chat room will lead to waste of time especially when users with slow internet connections will have to wait for his/her reply and if we state that the user is offline then the user won't migrate to chatroom

Comment: because [su] is not a social network

Comment: @sathya i agree with your comment suppose if the user views author's comment after an long time how can he/she start an chat without knowing the commented user is online?

Comment: Chat is stateful. Go to room, drop your message. If the author is inclined, they'll read and drop a reply.

Comment: an informal conversation can be stated as chat ,sir as per your comment we can simply mail him in detail and get the answer then there would be no need of chat! another thing sir without knowing whether the user is online staying in chatroom is waste of time

Comment: sir may i knew why my question was downvoted does i asked offthe topic or the question which was useless?

Comment: Down votes on Meta mean people disagree with your request.

Comment: Related question on Meta.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142809/improve-interactivity-between-askers-and-answerers-participants. See also my answer there. Chat is something "on side". If you reach the point on Stack Exchange in which you have to discuss something for long, then something is wrong, and not fitting the Q&A format.

Answer (score 5):

You can join a chatroom whenever you like. What has been said in the room when you were not there can later be read anyway.

If someone is online at the time, has no relevance. You can leave them a message or read their old message.

#### So why not email?

Because chat rooms are public by default. Others can join in and help. We like to work together on Stack Exchange. Even when just talking :)